# Buggy/jumpy CSS animation under Opera 12.x (Presto)?

Tags: css, animation, opera

Firstly, no, I will not drop support for Presto versions of Opera just yet, so I need to resolve this.

I've written an animation which makes a chevron (created with a div and the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, then skewing them with `transform`), and then I'm animating the Chevron to 'float' up and down repeatedly in simple harmonic motion, with the apex being at 48% of the top of the parent element, and the bottom being 52% of the top of the parent element.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hN8z/5/

Under all other browsers (including Opera 18), it performs flawlessly. In Opera 12.x for Windows, upon page load, the chevron begins by being offset from the bottom of the parent element by some arbitrary value, before 'jumping up' to its normal position, then animating, but leaving a 'trail' at the bottom of the `:after` pseudo element... really frustrating.

1. **Can anyone else replicate this behavior?**
2. **Can anyone find any evidence documenting this behavior?**
3. **Do any solutions exist?**
4. **If no, what possible workarounds could I consider?** (Disabling for Opera 12, altering animation properties, changing shape, etc).

Comment: I can reproduce this, and it seems this is a redraw issue, as when I open Dragonfly with "highlight selected node" on (causing the page to redraw at some point?), the "trail" disappeared and the animation works OK.

Comment: P.S. [It would be better](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) (more standard-compliant-ensurance) to put non-prefixed property at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/9hN8z/6/